# How to reformat date name in file list

Tags: groovy

I have a list of files:

- xxx_05102019023601017.csv
- xxx_05092019023601036.csv
- xxx_05082019023600900.csv

Using Groovy (or Java), I need to extract the date from the list of file names and reformat them so the year is leading. Like so...

- xxx_20190510023601017.csv
- xxx_20190509023601036.csv
- xxx_20190508023600900.csv

Is there a slick Groovy way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you want a way using Groovy, then why did you tag java? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: First find out pattern, use SimpleDateFormat and parse the string after extracting from file name using Java. If it is related to Groovy, remove the tag as @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the Java tag. I'm able to extract the name using regex, but am not familiar enough with date structures alter it.

Comment: @Sambit I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V., thanks for informing me about it. Good I am learning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the need to use date parsing/formatting

use just regular expression to swap two parts

```
def oldName = "xxx_05102019023601017.csv"
def newName = oldName.replaceAll(/^(\D+)(\d{4})(\d{4})/,'$1$3$2')
```

**out:**

```
xxx_20190510023601017.csv
```

**regexp explain:**

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/X0u9wv/1

**String.replaceAll( regex, replacement )**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

replacement - the string to be substituted for each match

`$1` `$2` and `$3` corresponds to each `(...)` in regexp, so I just swap 2-nd and 3-d groups in replacement

Comment: This is perfect! Can you break down how that Regex works? I've never seen the second argument given.

Comment: Nice regexp explanation.

Comment: It’s a nice and nicely explained regular expression solution, thanks. For my part I would still use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` because (1) they are specifically targeted towards dates and times (2) the code (although longer) will more directly tell the reader which parts (month, day, year) are swapped (3) the code will be easier and more natural to read (4) you will get stricter validation.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by daggett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56244943/642706) using regex is slick. If curious, here is the date-time way to handle it.

## *java.time*

> xxx_05102019023601017.csv

I am assuming the digits represent day-of-month, month, year, hour, minute, second, millisecond.

### Input

[Split your string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/642706) on the underscore by calling [`String::split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

```
String input = "foobar_05102019023601017.csv" ;
String[] parts = string.split( "_" ) ;
String part1 = parts[0]; // foobar
String part2 = parts[1]; // 05102019023601017.csv
```

Define a formatter to match the second part.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMuuuuHHmmssSSS'.csv'" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` object, since your input lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( part2 , f ) ;
```

### Output

Define a formatter for the output.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmssSSS" ) ;
```

Generate output.

```
String datetimeOutput = ldt.format( formatterOutput ) ;
String prefix = part1 + "_" ;
String suffix = ".csv" ;
String output = prefix + datetimeOutput + suffix ;
```

Or more succinctly, use a `StringBuilder` for a single-liner.

```
String output = new StringBuilder()
    .append( part1 ) 
    .append( "_" ) 
    .append( ldt.format( formatterOutput ) )
    .append( ".csv") 
    .toString() 
;
```

### ISO 8601

Your format is close to the “basic” variation of standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. I suggest using these standard formats wherever feasible. To comply, insert a `T` between the year-month-day portion and the hour-minute-second portion.

To do so, change the `DateTimeFormatter` pattern. Insert the letter inside a pair of single-quotes: `'T'`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssSSS" ) ;
```

### Zone/Offset

A date and a time without an assigned time zone or offset-from-UTC is ambiguous and therefore prone to misinterpretation. I suggest always including the zone or offset to communicate clearly.

If this date and time was meant to represent a moment in UTC (a good idea generally), append simply a `Z`. This letter means UTC, or an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The letter is pronounced “Zulu”.

```
String output = new StringBuilder()
    .append( part1 ) 
    .append( "_" ) 
    .append( ldt.format( formatterOutput ) )
    .append( "Z" ) 
    .append( ".csv") 
    .toString() 
;
```